# Is there anything like "Java shared libraries" for minimizing disk footprint of deployed applications?

Tags: java, scala, deployment, sbt, dependency-management

Let's imagine, I created a bunch of command line utilities, written in Scala and/or Java, and I'm using SBT to build them. They all use a couple of libraries, some of them pretty big, and in case of Scala, also the (not so small) Scala standard library.

I want to have these utilities in completely built form (runnable `.jar` files) to be able to instantly launch any of them and, if needed, also easily distribute them. But what I don't want is to include their dependencies in all of them, because they will be taking disk space.  Instead I want them to get dependencies from a shared folder at runtime, and the application jar should contain only "my" classes.

The question is, is there a standard way to accomplish this? If so, where must be shared `.jar`s located? Otherwise, what would you recommend to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `CLASSPATH` for this.

The JRE searched for classes in the `.jar` files named in the `CLASSPATH`.

Additionally all `.jar` files in the directory `jre/lib/ext` are used.

To find the complete serching in classpathes please consult the [official documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/findingclasses.html#A1012444).

Answer (score 2):

Something you might like to consider (although it will require slightly changing what you plan to do) is to have a local Maven repository.

You could have SBT publish libraries to it when they're built. Instead of building runnable JARs, you could run your applications via SBT, which would pull libraries from the local repository as/when required.

The benefit of this is that all the plumbing to do this is built into SBT, and it would make distribution trivial.

The downside is that you would have to run your apps via SBT instead of building runnable JARs. Whether that will work for you, I don't know.